# Why Oracle changes rowid with fetch?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a query like this:

```
select w.rowid, w.waclogin
  from tableA w, tableB wa, tableC a
 where wa.alucod = a.alucod
   and w.waclogin = wa.waclogin
   and a.cpf = '31808013875'
   and rownum <= 1;
```

The results are:

```
ROWID               WACLOGIN
AAA0CEAHSAABE07ABA  31808013875
```

But when I use fetch (for performance) the rowid returned is different:

```
select w.rowid, w.waclogin
  from tableA w, tableB wa, tableC a
 where wa.alucod = a.alucod
   and w.waclogin = wa.waclogin
   and a.cpf = '31808013875'
 fetch first row only;
```

Results in:

```
ROWID               WACLOGIN
AAA0DMAHaAAA+ZcAAX  31808013875
```

Why fetch changes the rowid?
For me this no makes sense.

### Update

When fetch is used, that row id returned is from table B, instead of table A.

[image: row id from 3 tables]

Comment: Are you sure the same row was fetched? Try to extend your query with column ora_rowscn.

Answer (score 5):

There are two rows in `tableA` with the same `wacLogin` value (but obviously different `rowID` values).  Neither of your queries specifies an `order by` so which of those rows is returned is arbitrary.  Presumably, there is a slightly different query plan being used for both queries so each one returns a different arbitrary row.  Of course, tomorrow, either or both queries could start returning a different arbitrary row if the query plan or physical organization of the table changes.  If you want the same row to be returned in both cases, you'd need to make both queries deterministic with an `order by` clause that uniquely orders the results.

Comment: relying on a ROWID isn't a great practice either - they can in fact change, best to use a UK/PK to specify a row

Comment: I agree @thatjeffsmith, but the whole code uses this and I can't change this right now.

Comment: @Justin I just have one line in Table A, but table B have two. I updated the question with a screenshot from PL/SQL Developer. Fetch returns me the Table B row id, instead of Table A row id.